# Android Emulator - Shnapshot option is missing?

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, snapshot

I can't figure out how to enable snapshot function on virtual devices. The option is grayed out and there is no setting when creating or editing a virtual device. I'm using the latest version of the SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3

Heres what my window looks like: [Create new Android Virtual Device](http://tinypic.com/r/2co3qc8/8)

SOLVED: Creation window had to be manually expanded to reveal the hidden options

Comment: when you are creating a new `Virtual device`. It has a radio button for "Snapshot" enable it.!

Comment: Like I said, there is no such option for me to check

Comment: try with updating the ADT for your eclipse..it should look like :) http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2u4ufqp&s=8

Comment: else best way to take screenshot of your screen using ctrl+printscreen option if ur using window machine :)

Comment: I'm using the latest. Could it be that my computer is not supported? I'm using a laptop Compaq nc8430. It has an old graphics card if that means anything...

Comment: This is ridiculous but i solved the problem by expanding the wiondow to reveal those options... This is the first time i see a creation window that is resizable and has no scroll bar to indicate that some options are hidden. They need to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't find emulation options in the AVD manager but you want to use "Use Host GPU" option, you can run your emulator like this():

```
emulator -avd <avd_name> -gpu on
```

or modify your emulator config file( path: `.android/avd/your_avd_name.avd/config.ini`)

add `hw.gpu.enabled=yes`